# Using Laravel 5 Sessions Externally

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I've figured out how to boot Laravel in an external script, but I can't seem to get Session::put() to stick.

```
$path = "/path/to/laravel/bootstrap/";

require $path . 'autoload.php';
$app = require_once $path . 'app.php';

$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel')
  ->handle(Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());

print_r(Session::all());
Session::put('test', 1);
```

Even after I refresh, this is the output:

```
Array ( 
    [_token] => emt8sZz7U6prnGUnHV889XPKwuhRCuMpVsAOfWW0 
    [flash] => Array ( 
        [old] => Array ( ) 
        [new] => Array ( ) 
    ) 
    [_previous] => Array ( 
        [url] => http://myurl.local  
    )
)
```

With no trace of my test variable. For some reason it doesn't make it into the Session.

**SOLUTION:**

Looks like I needed to call Session::save(). New problem below.

**NEW PROBLEM:**

I discovered that Laravel sessions work great when there is already a session in place. When there is no session, this approach does not create a new session. Specifically, the cookie (laravel_session) is not set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Following way works for laravel 5.2 
In my case, for some reason the session cookie does not appear on pages that has not a controller/action - was not described in the routes

```
 <?php
namespace App\Helpers;
use Session;

class SessionHelper extends \App\Auth\SessionData
{

/**
 * to init session on non laravel controller pages
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
static public function oldCodeInitSessionFoIfNotExists ($request)
{
    $cookieVarName     = $request->session()->getName();
    $sessionID         = $request->session()->getId();
    $sessionExpiration = config('session.lifetime')*60;
    $cookiePath        = config('session.path');
    $cookieDomain      = config('session.domain');

    setcookie($cookieVarName, $sessionID, time()+$sessionExpiration, $cookiePath, $cookieDomain);


}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried manually initiating the session from your external script? Something like this should do the trick:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE[$app['config']['session.cookie']])) {
    $id = $app['encrypter']->decrypt($_COOKIE[$app['config']['session.cookie']]);
    $app['session']->driver()->setId($id);
}

$app['session']->driver()->start();
```